# A ScrollViewer inside a Grid causes the row to not resize correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, grid, scrollviewer

I have a Grid with three rows, and a GridSplitter between the first two rows.  The third row contains a button.  When the GridSplitter is dragged to the center or lower part of the window, everything resizes fine.  When the GridSplitter is dragged to the top of the window, the second row fails to resize correctly and the third row gets cut off.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Width="300" MinHeight="300"  >
  <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MinHeight="130" />
      <RowDefinition MinHeight="50" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Aquamarine"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" >
      <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Orange"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Close" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Click="Close_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But the GridSplitter is not between the first two rows.  The GridSplitter is on the first (0) row.

Comment: Sorry - initial description could be improved.  The problem occurs when the gridsplitter is dragged up, and then when the window is shrunk the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your row MinHeight values are the culprit.

I tested your code and the issue you're describing happens when I resize the window, not when I drag the splitter.

Creating a second grid and moving the button out will help.

**CODE:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Width="300" MinHeight="300"  >
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="130" />
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Aquamarine"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" />
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" >
                <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Orange"/>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Close" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know, but they are required.

Comment: You'll notice that the Grid as a whole only requires ~210 vertical space, and the Window MinHeight is set to 300.

Comment: Why is the min height required?  Can you just set the MinHeight on the Rectangle?

Comment: Maybe - in the real app there is a bunch of UI objects in the top row, and the second row contains a DataGrid.

Comment: Just checked - if you set the MinHeight on the rectangle, the row can still be shrunk to less than the MinHeight - the UI objects in the row get cut off.

Comment: Forgot to add that you need to make sure to set ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" for the grid splitter.

Comment: Umm - I just tested that code and it still fails.  My initial description could have been improved - yes the problem occurs when the splitter is dragged near the top, and then the window as a whole is shrunk.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Note that moving the GridSplitter to its own row doesn't make a difference - the important part was wrapping it inside another grid.  Also, not that there is still a bug - when the splitter is moved to the top, if the vertical scroll bar is visible in the scrollviewer it's impossible to drag the splitter down.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I'll edit my answer to remove moving the grid splitter to its own row.